# Prove $\cos (n\theta) \neq \frac{1}{2}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given that $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{1}{4}$.

Prove $\cos (n\theta) \neq 1$, for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

My attempt:
If $\cos(n\theta) = 1$,
then $e^{in\theta} = 1$.

$e^{in\theta} = e^{i(n-1)\theta} \cdot e^{i \theta}$

If $e^{in\theta} = 1$, then $e^{i(n-1)\theta} = e^{i(-1)\theta}$.

Then $(-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}i)^{n-1} = (-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}i)$.

However, I failed to prove that $(-\frac{1}{4} + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}i)^{n-1} \neq (-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}i)$, for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is it $\cos n\theta\neq\frac12$ as in your question title, or $\cos n\theta\neq 1$ as in the second line of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction that $\cos(n \theta)=1$.

Use the identity
$$\cos( \theta) = \frac{e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}}{2}$$
Call $z=e^{i \theta}$, then $z$ satisfies the following equation
$$\frac{z + z^{-1}}{2}=- \frac{1}{3}$$
which can be rewritten as
$$z^{2} + \frac{2}{3}z+1=0 $$

Clearly, the polynomial $x^2+ \frac{2}{3}x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $z$ over the rational numbers (because it is irreducible over the rationals). This means that $z$ is not an algebraic integer.

On the other hand, $\cos(n \theta)=1$ implies that $z^n=1$.
This means that $z$ is a root of unity, and in particular it is an algebraic integer. This is a contradiction.

EDIT: if you don't know what an algebraic integer is, look at the following theorem:

> Let $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ be an algebraic number over the rationals. Then TFAE:
>
> 1. the monic minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has integer coefficients
> 2. $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients
>
> In such a case, $\alpha$ is called an algebraic integer.